# Can not call getApplicationContext() inside a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing an application on Android Froyo system, everything is fine, except that when I create a service, and the service will spawn several thread. In one of the thread, I want to stop the service.
Apparently stopService() is out of scope in the thread class, and so is the getApplicationContext() calls.
So inside a thread, can I get the current context and how?

Thanks

Comment: You almost never need `getApplicationContext()`. `Activity` and `Service` are both subclasses of `Context`.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your own context

```
private Context mContext;
```

and use insted of `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try MyService.this.stopSelf(). Or if that doesn't work, you can store a reference to your service when it's created. In your oncreate you can do Context ctx = this. And then in your thread ctx.stopSelf()